# .NET Framework 2.0をターゲットとしてビルドされたWindowsデスクトップアプリケーションを、Windows 10とWindows 11 それぞれで動作させるとUIの表示に差がある

Tags: windows, visual-studio, .net, windows-10

Windows 10, Windows 11に全く同じミドルウェアをインストールし、テーマ等OA周りの設定も合わせられるものは全て合わせても、.NET Framework 2.0をターゲットとしてビルドしたWindows Formsを継承したフォーム上のUIに差が出ます。動作環境は.NETFRAMEWORK3.5上です。

例えばテキストボックスでは、Windows 10ではテキストボックスの四辺は枠線に囲まれていますが、Windows 11では下線のみに見えて、上左右の線が見えません。

また、チェックボックスでは、チェック時にWindows 10とWindows 11でチェック部分と塗りつぶし部分の色が逆転しています。
原因と対処方法などを教えてください。

Comment: 「ミドルウェア」って何ですか？　「Windowsデスクトップアプリ」って何ですか？ Windows Forms? WPF? その他？　「.NET Framework 2.0をターゲット」とのことですが、間違いないですか？

Comment: windows 10 と 11 の違いというよりは画面解像度と拡大縮小比率の違いだったりしませんか？デスクトップの上で右クリック→ディスプレイ設定で確認できます。 100% とか 125% とかなんとか。

Comment: 画面解像度と拡大縮小比率は同じにしてあります。

Comment: ミドルウェアはssmsや、LEADTOOLS、CrystalReportsです

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 原因

Windows のバージョンごとの固有の視覚効果がアプリに適用されるため。

## 対処方法 1 (C# の場合)

アプリに適用される視覚効果をオフにし、クラシックスタイルで起動するようにすると、Windows のバージョンごとで見た目の違いがなくなります。

Windows Forms でデスクトップ アプリを開発しているのであれば、Program.cs 内の　Application.EnableVisualStyles() を実行しないようにすれば、クラシック スタイルで起動するようになります。

```
internal static class Program
{   
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        // OS のルック & フィールを適用しない
        // Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Application.EnableVisualStyles は、対象 OS の固有の視覚効果を適用する設定です。

https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles

このコードを実行しないようにすれば、クラシックスタイルでアプリが表示されます。

[image: win11 と Classic Style]

上記画像は、両方とも Windows 11 環境で、左が、EnableVisualStyles 実行時のコントロールの見た目、EnableVisualStyles を実行しなかった場合(クラシックスタイル)のコントロールの見た目となります。

## 対処方法 2 (VB.NET の場合)

VB.NET の場合では、[プロジェクト] - [プロパティ] - [XP Visual スタイルを有効にする] をオフにすることで、アプリに適用される視覚効果をオフにできます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

## 対処方法 3 (未検証)

コード編集したくない場合には、同様のことをレジストリの設定で行うことができる可能性があります。(私の環境では、動作しませんでした。)

以下のいずれかのレジストリ エントリに対してキーと値を設定することで、アプリをクラシックスタイルで起動できるかもしれません。

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers

設定するキーと値は以下です。

- キー: アプリのフルパス。例) c:\testApp001.exe
- 値: ~ DISABLETHEMES (チルダ + スペース + DISABLETHEMES を設定)

私の環境では、変化はありませんでした。よろしければ、効果があるかを確認いただければと思います。

Comment: よくわかっておらず申し訳ないのですが、開発したアプリケーションのテキストボックスのプロパティなどの見た目ではなく、OS自体のテーマなどが適用されているのを、強制的にやめるコードを埋め込むという認識でよいですか？
ただ、コードを修正や、再ビルドは避けたいと思っています。

Comment: ビルドがダメなら何だったらいいのですか？　EXE ファイルのプロパティ画面上「互換モード」とか「高DPI設定の変更」とかならやってよい？

Comment: サンプルの画像を拝見するに、当方の事象とほぼ同じと思われます。ですので、奥の手としてその方法を使わせていただこうかと思います。ちなみに、「互換モード」とか「高DPI設定の変更」とかの設定はどの項目をどのように設定なされるおつもりでしょうか？実は当方に実行環境がなく、試行もできない状態なのでためしようがなく、、、

Comment: 最終的にはうまくいく対処方法の中から上司と相談して選択ということになるかと存じます。

Comment: 私の環境では変化ありませんでしたが、レジストリでのクラシックスタイルの適用方法を追記したので、可能であれば確認いただければと思います。

Comment: 申し訳ないのですが、VBだとどのようにコードを修正することになるのでしょうか？

Comment: VB.NET でもオブジェクトモデルは、変わらないと思うので、Application.EnableVisualStyles の記述があるか探してみてください。あれば、その部分をコメントアウトか削除してみてください。